# responsive html table links not working on iPad

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive table using css. The links work fine on all devices including my iPhone but not on the iPad. I've searched for fixes but can only find jquery fixes. Any help appreciated.

CSS:

```
/* General Table Style */

table.responsivetable {
border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 97%;
margin-left: 1.5%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

th { 
 background-color: #9eafd5;
color: #0c0065;
font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Palatino, serif;
font-weight: 700;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
background: #d3dbec; 
}

.responsivetable td, .responsivetable th {
padding: 6px;
border: 1px solid #0c0065;
text-align: left;
}

/* Make Table Responsive --- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width:     1024px)  {

.responsivetable table, .responsivetable thead, .responsivetable th, .responsivetable tr, .responsivetable td {display: block;
}

/* Hide table headers (but not display:none, for accessibility) */
.responsivetable thead tr {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}

.responsivetable tr {
border: 1px solid #0c0065;
}

.responsivetable td {
/* Behave like a row */
border: none;
padding-left: 30%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0c0065;
position: relative;
}

.responsivetable td:before {
/* Now, like a table header */
position: absolute;
/* Top / left values mimic padding */
top: 6px; left: 10px;
width: 45%;
padding-right: 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Palatino, serif;
font-weight: 700;
}

/* -- LABEL THE DATA -- */

.responsivetable td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Title"; }

.responsivetable td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Name"; }

.responsivetable td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Email"; }


}
/* End responsive query */
#TableBound a:link  {
color: #4162af;
text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main"><h1>Attorneys</h1>
<div id="TableBound">
<table class="responsivetable" border="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="titleBold lightblue">Partner</td>
<td><a href="bio-Howard.html">Joseph C. Howard, Jr.</a></td>
<td><a href="mailto:jhoward@hrmrlaw.com">jhoward@hrmrlaw.com</a></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="titleBold">Partner</td>
<td><a href="bio-Rome.html">Henry D. Rome</a></td>
<td><a href="mailto:hrome@hrmrlaw.com">hrome@hrmrlaw.com</a></td>
</tr>
```

I know it's the table that is preventing the link to work, when I created the links without the table they work fine.

Can anyone suggest a work around or solution?

Comment: Don't even know what your problem is

Comment: When using an iPad, the links in in the table do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the culprit, when position: relative; (in .responsive td css) the ipad does not let you click on the link.

My solution:

```
.responsivetable td {
/* Behave like a row */
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0c0065;
}

.responsivetable td:before {
/* Now, like a table header */
position: relative;
/* Top / left values mimic padding */
left: 10px;
width: 45%;
padding-right: 25px;
white-space: nowrap;
font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Palatino, serif;
font-weight: 700;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to make it responsive with flex

```
.table-res{
        td {
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            word-break: break-all;
            display: flex;
        }
        td:before {
            position: relative;
            width: 54%;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
}
```